# lambda function calling 2 additional lambda functions

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I'm just learning about Lambda functions in Python and am confused as to what is happening here.

```
z = 3
e = lambda x: lambda y: lambda: x + y + z
e(0)(1)()
"returns 4"

f = lambda z: x + z
f(3)
"returns ?"
```

I somewhat understand the first lambda chain having rewritten it in terms of normal def statements and outside of each def statement, returning the function that was just defined...

```
def i(x):
    def j(y):
        def k(z):
            return x + y + z
        return k(z)
    return j(y)
```

But I'm not sure how the f = lambda z: x + z is working here

Thanks for any help!

Comment: ... it doesn't return, it throws a `NameError`

Comment: The second `x` is not defined. Please check code and update.

Comment: in the context of the problem, both the 'e' and 'f' assignments are happening in the same interpreter session.  In that case is x not already the formal parameter of one of the lambda functions that is ultimately assigned to e?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your translation of the first batch of lambdas is not quite right. It should be:

```
def i(x):
    def j(y):
        def k():               # no z argument
            return x + y + z
        return k               # return the function k, without calling it
    return j                   # same here, just return j without calling it
```

This works when you call it with `i(0)(1)()`. In the inner function `x` and `y` are looked up in the encosing scopes (finding `0` and `1`), and `z` is looked up as a global variable.

Your second lambda is equivalent to:

```
def g(z):
    return x + z
```

This doesn't work, since `x` is not defined as a global. If you renamed the `z` argument to `x`, then it would work since the `z` in the sum being returned would be the global `z` that the previous code used and `x` would be the argument. If the lambda was working for you, you must have defined an `x` global that you haven't shown in your code snippets.

Comment: Turns out I had overlooked an earlier assignment of x.  Thank you for clarifying the function declaration ladder as well!